# recursive SQL no indexes

Tags: sql, recursion

I have a list of serial numbers that have been collated (over many years) by hand into Excel Sheets.

When we produce an item, we give it a unique (that day) serial number and ship it.
The item WILL be returned, whereupon we will refurbish it, and apply a new serial number.

Items can return hundreds of times, each time the old serial is recorded and the new serial is recorded alongside, in an Excel sheet that is new each day.

I need to find the refurbish -> return history of all the possible items.

So I have imported the sheets into MS SQL 2K8: date, old serial(x), new serial(y)

I can use PHP to labouriously search for serial x if found, record it, make search x parameter == y and keep going until no more records found.

But I feel sure there is a way to get the list with SQL statements alone.  But I'm stumped - any clues?

Comment: I don't have the time to write it up right now on how exactly to do it but a [recursive Common Table Expression](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186243(v=sql.105).aspx) is exactly what you are looking for.

Comment: what does the "record" it look like. I'm not 100% as to what you are logging. Are you trying to show a list of the first serial number and all of the additional ones?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is, using a recursive CTE.  To get all the "new serial numbers" after an old one:

```
with cte as (
      select s.oldserial, s.newserial
      from serials s
      where oldserial = @x
      union all
      select s.oldserial, s.newserial
      from serials s join
           cte
           on s.newserial = cte.oldserial
    )
select *
from cte;
```

To get the predecessors, change the `on` conditions to `cte.newserial = s.oldserial`.